# Giving a physicsBody a constant force

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a ball bouncing up and down. I've accomplished this by setting it's physics body up like this:

```
linearDamping = 0
friction = 0
restitution = 1
```

And then just `applyForce(CGVectorMake(0, 10))` in the setup call. The ball is now bouncing up and down, up and down with not interruption.

Now I want to add player control. The player can move the ball sideways. I could do this by just setting the balls velocity when the controls are pressed. BUT by doing that I lose all the stuff the physics engine gives me.

Here's a short snippet of code I have right now:

```
  override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Apply damping only in x */
    if !movingLeft && !movingRight {
      let dx = ball!.physicsBody!.velocity.dx * xAlpha
      let dy = ball!.physicsBody!.velocity.dy
      ball!.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx, dy)
    }

    if movingRight {
      ball!.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(ballVelocityX, 0))
    }
    if movingLeft {
      ball!.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-ballVelocityX, 0))
    }
  }
```

The problem, as you might imagine, is that applying impulse upon impulse on each frame like this makes the ball go superfast, which is not what I want, when the controls are held down. But if I apply the force only on `keyDown` the ball will stop moving in that direction once the ball hits something. And also the `keyDown` event works wonky on OS X (because of key repeat settings).

So what I want to do is apply an impulse in the `update` function in a way that makes the force of the ball not exceed my limit but also not go away completely if the ball hits something.

Comment: Have you tried applying a force instead of an impulse in the update function?

Comment: Yes, the effect is the same. Only difference is that with applyForce the ball will accelerate up to the given vector.